# I need loop components using @for loop in angular 17

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I'm having a list with id, label and component as values, I want to loop the components in a html template in angular 17, but I'm getting 'class _TabComponent { }' as output in html page

```
@for(component of components; track component.id){
    <mat-tab label={{component.label}} class="">
        {{component.component}}
    </mat-tab>
}
```

Comment: You need to use `NgComponentOutlet`: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader